# showing an error The method setNeedsSound(boolean) is undefined for the type EngineOptions

Tags: android, andengine

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    instance = this;
    mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera)).setNeedsSounds(true);
}
```

showing an error while enabling the sound it is showing an error
The method setNeedsSound(boolean) is undefined for the type EngineOptions

also tried

```
return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera)).getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
```

but showing error 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from AudioOptions to EngineOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way

```
final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an extra `)` in your code. Try:

```
return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera).setNeedsSounds(true);
```